# Function maintains internal state in C

Tags: c, strtok

How can a function in C maintain it's internal state?

For example `strtok()` - when calling `strtok(NULL, del)` the function continue working on a previous string.

Comment: static or global variables

Comment: By being dangerous to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It contains internal variables to keep track of things, declared as `static`. This is also the very reason why such functions aren't safe to use in multi-threaded programs.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by declaring local variables as `static`:

```
unsigned int some_state_function( void )
{
  static unsigned int internal_state = 0;  // keeps track of the number 
  ...                                      // of times the function has been
  return internal_state++;                 // called - useless, but illustrative
}
```

The variable `internal_state` has `static` storage duration, meaning storage for it is allocated *and initialized* at program startup and held until the program terminates; its lifetime extends beyond the lifetime of the function.  In this case the initialization is redundant (`static` objects are initialized to `0` or the equivalent), but it's there to illustrate the concept - the initialization occurs once, at program startup, not when the function is called.

However, the *identifier* `internal_state` is local to `some_state_function` - it's not visible outside the function.

`strtok` does something similar - it has a local `static` pointer that keeps track of the string you're processing.

Comment: The function keeps pointers to it's static variables? how does it know "where to find them"?

Comment: @Daniel - The same way it knows where to find local variables and function arguments.  Variables, regardless of scope or storage duration, are (typically) not stored in the same memory region as the function code itself.  If you look at the generated assembly code, you'll see operands specified as either offsets from a given address, or as a symbol.